# UEFI firmware corrupt? Neither ethernet nor wireless controller detected anymore

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, ethernet, uefi, flashing

**The problem**

My computer is a **64-bit Acer Apsire V5-572G** currently running with Arch Linux.
I wanted to use some programs that dont run with Wine. So i set up a Windows-To-Go on an external hdd. Upon booting it said something like `Devices are being prepared...`. However after booting I wasnt able to reach the internet anymore,
neither wired, nor wireless (it worked before!).

I suspect UEFI firmware damage for reasons given furhter below.
Do i now need to flash my UEFI? If so can you give any guidance (Where to get the correct file, how to flash, what to pay attention to?)? Or do i even have to replace the whole motherboard?

**Symptoms**

- The system does not properly shut down any more, you have to manually power it off.
- The touch pad is not recognized any more
- Some weird random key mapping happens after some time, like if you press P it writes * or instead of i it writes 5.
- After selecting exit & save in my UEFI menu it now doesnt save, exit and reboot any more, but instead, save, freeze and power off.
- On several different Linux live systems, Windows-To-Go and Arch on my
  hdd all dont show any of the devices mentioned (ethernet and wireless controller) after lspci or
  in the device manager (as network adapter) respectively.
- Corrupted entries in the UEFI-menu, e.g.    Serial Number is 8 or
  Manufacturer is left blank.

**What i tried**

I thought thats not too bad, so I restarted my computer with Arch Linux. There, too i was unable to connect to the internet.

So i typed `sudo wifi-menu`
and it returned the following message:

```
Invalid interface specification
Usage: wifi-menu [-h | --help] [-o | --obscure] [INTERFACE]

Interactively connect to a wireless network on INTERFACE using netctl.
If only one wireless interface is available, INTERFACE can be omitted.
```

`lspci` returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev ff)
```

**No controllers detected!**

I also tried to reset the UEFI to the original configuration with no improvement (thereafter disbaling secure boot again of course).

**Additional information:**

Motherboard is an Acer Dazzle CX.

Although my processor is an Intel i7-3537U.

Please help, i need internet access on my machine ASAP.
Thx in advance!

Comment: You can get the latest BIOS (that is what they call it) from Acer's website. The instructions should be on their site somewhere.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thanks for the hint. Do you think this is the correct software (click on BIOS/Firmware) http://www.acer.de/ac/de/DE/content/drivers/4722;-;Aspire%20V5-572G ? To me it seems kind of dubious, because it only mentions adding support for brazilian keyboards. Also i did not find first-hand instructions on how to flash the BIOS. In the user manual contains only a note stating that it is not very likely that you have to mess with the BIOS-application.

Comment: Even the BIOS download zip file does not contain instructions :( Also, it is possible that some bugs were fixed in the latest BIOS, but not mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a **partial solution**, curing the following symptoms:

- Ethernet and network controller not detected.
- Touchpad not detected.

I did a hard reset (physical) reset of the UEFI by (the software reset via the UEFI-menu did exactly nothing):

- Removing the AC power.
- Taking out the battery.
- Pressing the power button for 15 seconds to remove any residual charge from capacitors.

However the UEFI-menu is still corrupted and also shutdown does not work properly. As of now strange keymapping has not occured yet, but maybe later, stay tuned.

I found a UEFI/BIOS flashing software on the official acer site, but did not dare to use it. Link here: http://www.acer.de/ac/de/DE/content/drivers .